# Signed XAP deployed to IIS is still Unverified for the user (client machine)

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser, xap

Just a problem. I was able to deploy my signed silverlight OOB on IIS on our Server. However despite that the signed xap was deployed to IIS, when accessing the app on the other machine (client) the Installation Menu still shows warning(Unverified) publisher. I understand that in order for the client to enjoy auto-update feature of silverlight oob app, the installation oob app should has been signed. I discovered that in order for the client to see the oob app as signed application, this client machine should install first the certificate used by the server for that app. Is there any way to resolve the issue? Its not ideal for every client to install first the certificate, the same certificated used to sign the oob app to enjoy auto-update feature. Try the issue above and you will replicate the issue.

Help please.

Comment: Works for me. We purchased a real code signing certificate from a trusted authority. Not free, but not that expensive either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get a proper signed certificate (ie, signed by a certificate authority). a self signed cert will not do.

try startssl, they have the cheapest ssl certs

Answer (score 0):

Why do we need a monetary certificate for an intranet solution? Sorry this is not constructive.

Comment: If it was on an intranet then you could probably install the certificate on the computers that needed it fairly easy.